Messages app keeps crashing
For a few days now, the Message app keeps crashing.  There has not been a system update for a while, but I do check and update all apps daily.

If I open the Messages app, it opens
I can scroll up and down
As soon as I select a person, it crashes in a few seconds
Sometimes I can press a few letters, but they are lost after the crash.

I have restarted the phone, to no effect.  I am having to call back everyone that messages me.
This is the built in Messages app for sms.  I am using Samsung Note20 Ultra.  Any ideas anyone?

Have you checked logcat for errors related to messages app and messages subsystem (reception of SMS)?

Backup the messages and clear data and cache and check. If that doesn't help, uninstall all updates to this app and let it reinstall updates on it's own to rule out botched updates causing this//Also check on device forums if this is a common problem, in which case you are the mercy of Samsung and it's time to switch to an alternative app
